# Data is not saving in the local Storage?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

i'm trying to get the favorites list using localstorage. I have a listview with number of items when i clicked on the item it opens and contains some data.In the same page i have a button with "Bookmark". when i clicked on that button that particular page has to added in that favourites list. When i'm trying to get the list of favorites it doesn't store any data.

Js code:

```
$(".addToFavoritesDiv").click(function() {
                    var path = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');
                    //alert(path);
                    //var store = localStorage.path;
                                    s += "<li><a href=\"index.html?id="+ localStorage.path +"\"></a></li>";
                $('#favoritesList').append(s);
                //alert("appended");
                                    $('#favoritesList').listview('refresh');
                });
$("#fav").on('click', function(event){
                //get our fav
                var fav;
                            var favs;
                for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                            fav = favs[i];
                             }      
                s += "<li><a href=\"index.html?id=""\" class="item"></a></li>";
                $('#favoritesList').append(s);
                addToStorage(fav);
        });

function addToStorage(favList)
{
$(".item").on('click', function (){
  var i = $('.item').index(this);
  console.log(i);
         localStorage['results'] = JSON.stringify(favList[i]);
          storedItem = (localStorage['results']) ;
            console.log(storedItem);
             alert("this post was added to local storage");

            //retrieve  list item
             var retrievedItem = localStorage.getItem(['results']);
             console.log( 'retrieved: ' + retrievedItem);
    }
```

Can anyone help me to get the solution for this it would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `console.log(favList[i])` and see if in fact you are storing something

Answer (score 0):

The following line

```
localStorage.getItem(['results']);
```

should be

```
localStorage.getItem('results');
```

Comment: thanks for your response..but i tried like this also still not working